# Ошибка при генерации контроллеров Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Мне нужно сгенерировать контроллеры в Ruby On Rails.
После ввода команды:

```
rails generate controller StaticPages home about faq
```

Вылезает данная ошибка:

> FATAL: Listen error: unable to monitor directories for changes.

В чем может быть ошибка? И как её можно исправить?

**`P.S: RoR version 6.1.4.1`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно увеличить количество файлов, доступных для отслеживания.

По умолчанию ***inotify*** используется в ***Linux*** для мониторинга каталогов на предмет изменений. Нередко можно столкнуться с системным ограничением на количество файлов, которые вы можете отслеживать. Например, в ***Ubuntu Lucid's*** (64bit) ограничение ***inotify*** установлено на 8192.

Вы можете узнать текущий лимит наблюдения за файлами ***inotify***, выполнив следующие действия:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Если этого предела недостаточно для отслеживания всех файлов внутри каталога, то для правильной работы необходимо увеличить этот предел.
Вы можете временно установить новый предел с помощью:

```
$ sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Если вы хотите сделать лимит постоянным, используйте:

```
$ sudo sh -c "echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 >> /etc/sysctl.conf"
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло, ошибка ушла)